# How do I force a maximum of one instance of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

Since nautilus can open tabs, won't it be better if there was an option to force only 1 instance of it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think Nautilus has that. With Unity in 11.10, I've actually stopped using tabs in Nautilus since it's more comfortable to switch between windows using alt+(the key above tab).